# WooCommerce Add to cart redirection to previous URL

Tags: php, wordpress, session, redirect, woocommerce

At the request of users, I need the add to cart button on the individual product page to redirect users to the previous page after clicking add product to cart.

With [following code](https://jeroensormani.com/redirect-users-after-add-to-cart/), customer returns to a specific page (in this case the shop page):

```
function my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect( $url ) {

    $url = get_permalink( 311 ); // URL to redirect to (1 is the page ID here)

    return $url;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'my_custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

with this code the users return to a specific page by means of the page id. in this case it is the store page

I would like users to be redirected to the previous page to see the product, any idea that can help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Following this method is fine, but you'd need to store the page ID somehow and recall that after they hit the add to cart. You could then redirect them based on that. You could potentially also use the JS `window.history.back();` to accomplish the task too. But that assumes you're adding to cart via JS.

Comment: you should be able to simply reference the referrer page with javascript or php within your success logic.. .header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Answer (score 1):

2021 Update

The following will save to WC Session a short Url history that Will allow, on add to cart, to redirect customer to previous URL:

```
// Early enable customer WC_Session
add_action( 'init', 'wc_session_enabler' );
function wc_session_enabler() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() || is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( isset(WC()->session) && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
        WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
    }
}

// Set previous URL history in WC Session
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_request_history' );
function wc_request_history() {
    // Get from WC Session the request history
    $history = (array) WC()->session->get('request_history');

    // Keep only 2 request Urls in the array
    if( count($history) > 1){
        $removed = array_shift($history);
    }

    $current_url = ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if( ! in_array($current_url, $history) ) {
        // Set current url request in the array
        $history[] = $current_url;
    }

    // Save to WC Session the updated request history
    WC()->session->set('request_history', $history);
}

// The add to cart redirect to previous URL
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'add_to_cart_redirect_to_previous_url' );
function add_to_cart_redirect_to_previous_url( $redirect_url ) {
    // Get from WC Session the request history
    $history = (array) WC()->session->get('request_history');

    if ( count($history) == 2 ) {
        $redirect_url = reset($history);
    } else {
        // Other custom redirection (optional)
    }

    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I check and it work nice, can I show message to let the user know the product added?
Now it return to the pervious page without message, it look like reload, there is an option to set the return the shop link in the cart so it will be link to the pervious page?

Comment: I opened new question as you asked
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66027579/woocommerce-redirection-to-previous-page

Comment: Is it the place to ask about problem I faced with the answer? I can't edit pages and template with Elementor after adding your code

Comment: @hanan-mstudio I have updated my answer… It should solve that issue. Also note that this answer is made for single product page add to cart, so in this case the message that the product has been added to cart is displayed.