# WooCommerce redirection to previous page

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, cart

I using `https://sitename.com/?add-to-cart={$product_id}` to add product to cart. I found [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63158723/woocommerce-add-to-cart-redirection-to-previous-url/63161657#63161657) that allows to return to previous visited page when adding a product to cart.

But this miss the option to let the user know that the product has been added to the cart. How can I show them message to show that the products was added?

Any idea?

Comment: The rule on StackOverFlow is one question at the time, so I have removed your 2nd question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it is relevant to my question